# jQuery fill input not populating form with information passed on url

Tags: jquery

My Wordpress website has php and jQuery code that interprets input from the url and places it on the webpage in a form so the user does not have to enter it manually. The user email is passed in the url, then the user login name is then retrieved from Wordpress with get_user_by ('email', $invite_email ); This works correctly. An example of the variable values in fillInputs is:

fillInputs=...jQuery('input[name="name1"]').val('EnglishWithFriendsAnywhere');jQuery('input[name="email1"]').val('EnglishWithFriendsAnywhere@gmail.com');

The population in the form of the login name and email is not working.

[image: Name1 Email1]

[image: chrome element]

[image: location]
It worked correctly a few months ago and the form information was populated from the url parameters.
Now the input from the URL correctly interpreted but it is not populated in the webform.

No errors are showing in wordpress debug.log when logging is activated.
The Inspector window in chrome browser displays so much information that I do not understand where to look.

Question: What is the best way to debug this part of the code to understand why the form is not filling in?

**2 Steps to reproduce :**
Step 1: Copy and paste this URL into browser:

```
https://english-alps.com/auth/?authUID=44jzb0wEpbTI5easNAicDeLZPek2
```

Step 2: Copy and paste this URL into browser:

```
https://english-alps.com/lesson/schedule-on-line-english-classroom/?location_id=10&invited_email=englishwithfriendsanywhere@gmail.com
```

I found ea-frontend-bootstrap-css in Chrome

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="ea-frontend-bootstrap-css" href="https://english-alps.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-appointments/css/eafront-bootstrap.css?ver=3.0.15" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Here is the the code which I think fills in the form

```
function explode() {
            jQuery(".uniquetime a").first().trigger('click');
            {$fillInputs}
        }
           jQuery(document).on('click', '.uniquetime > a', function (event) {
            {$fillInputs}
        });
    
  
        // jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('{$cssSelector}').val('{$location}');
            jQuery('{$cssSelector}').bind('change', function () {
                // console.log("here I am");
                setTimeout(explode, 3000);
            });
    
            jQuery('{$cssSelector}').trigger('change');
        // });
    EOT;
                    return $script;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'EasyApp_WT_Plugin' ) ) {
    class EasyApp_WT_Plugin {

        /**
         * Static property to hold our singleton instance
         *
         */
        static $instance = false;

        public function __construct() {
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'init_scripts'));
        }

        public function init_scripts() {
           if ( ! wp_script_is( 'jquery', 'done' ) ) {
               wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
           }
            wp_add_inline_script( 'ea-front-bootstrap', $this->generateScript() );
        }

        public static function getInstance() {
            if ( ! self::$instance ) {
                self::$instance = new self;
            }

            return self::$instance;
        }


        /**
         * JS Script for:
         *
         * - Select option for Location based on location `location_id` added in request
         * - Fill Name and Email field based on `invited_email` param in request
         *
         * @return string JS code
         */
        public function generateScript() {
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            $email        = $current_user->user_email;
            $cssSelector  = '[name=location]';

            if (  ! isset( $_REQUEST['location_id'] ) || $_REQUEST['location_id'] === '' )  {
                return '';
            }

            $invited_email = $_REQUEST['invited_email'];

            $seprate_email = explode( ',', $invited_email );
            $location      = $_REQUEST['location_id'];

                   echo "email='"; echo $email;echo "' ";
                   echo "invited_email='"; echo $invited_email;echo "' ";
                   echo "location='";echo $location;echo "' ";
            $fillInputs = '';

            $counter = 1;

            foreach ( $seprate_email as $invite_email ) {

                // $uemail = get_user_by_email( $invite_email );
                 $uemail = get_user_by ('email', $invite_email );

                $fillInputs .= "jQuery('input[name=\"name" . $counter . "\"]').val('" . $uemail->data->user_login . "');";
                $fillInputs .= "jQuery('input[name=\"email" . $counter . "\"]').val('" . $uemail->data->user_email . "');";
                $counter ++;
            }

                echo"fillInputs=..."; echo($fillInputs);

            $script = <<<EOT
    function explode() {
        jQuery(".uniquetime a").first().trigger('click');
        {$fillInputs}
    }
       jQuery(document).on('click', '.uniquetime > a', function (event) {
        {$fillInputs}
    });


    // jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('{$cssSelector}').val('{$location}');
        jQuery('{$cssSelector}').bind('change', function () {
            // console.log("here I am");
            setTimeout(explode, 3000);
        });

        jQuery('{$cssSelector}').trigger('change');
    // });
EOT;
                return $script;
        }
```

Comment: and what exactly is not populating? please provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: updated question with example of data. I have also tried to debug this with vscode and xdebug but I was not successful.

Comment: This could happen if an element with name "location" was removed from the page or it appears after the script on your first image. Have you tried executing the code on document ready? (these lines are commented out). Anyway this is not reproducible example.

Comment: uncommented the document ready part and it works.....I will try and research what this means and if this can be used in this state.

Comment: My guess is, an element named "location" was declared below the script. So it doesn't exists by the time the script runs. This is a well known issue with js. That's why you need `$(document).ready()`, to make sure all elements loaded before running that code.